# How do i display department_id, last_name and minimum salary for each department?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

```
SELECT department_id, last_name, min(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id, last_name
HAVING min(salary) < 5000;
```

The query above will not give me the minimum salary for each department...rather i get multiple rows returned
How do i get only single result i.e the person with the minimum salary fro each department

Also i need to format the salary so that the it displays like $2,500...a thousand separator and a dollar at the beginning

Comment: Let an above layer take care of the display format.

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query to return each department's minimum salary. Join with that result.

```
SELECT e1.department_id, e1.last_name, e1.salary
from employees e1
join (select department_id, min(salary) salary
      from employees
      group by department_id) e2
  on e1.department_id = e1.department_id and e1.salary = e2.salary
where e1.salary < 5000
```

Will return both employees if two from the same departement has the same minimum salary.